# In reinforce algorithm (policy gradient), why is the reward not dependent upon the policy parameters?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, policy-gradient

The following is the precursor to the policy gradient algorithm

[image]

Why is the return $r(\tau)$ over the trajectory taken out of the gradient as if it is constant w.r.t the policy parameters $\theta$. Is it not that if the trajectory $\tau$ depends upon the parameters then the return should too